# Is there a way to add a label to a <Line> in Recharts, but not on every datapoint?

Tags: recharts

We have a LineChart in Recharts, and want to add labels to the lines themselves, but noticed that the label attribute of  applies the label to every single datapoint of the line instead of just to the [line](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Line) itself.

Is there a way to add a label to the entire line similar to how [reference line](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ReferenceLine) works?